# I want to use gatsby.js and strapi v3 to create pagination. But I get an error and can't make it. gatsby-awesome-pagination

Tags: gatsby

https://blakey.co/blog/pagination-with-strapi-and-gatsby
I copied and pasted the code from this site.

My strapi collection is Post,Category

allStrapiArticle ⇨ allStrapiPost

I made it exactly as shown on this page. However, I got the following error

> ERROR #11325
> Your site's "gatsby-node.js" created a page with a component that doesn't exist.
> The path to the missing component is
> "/Users/t/WebDevelopment/xxxxx/src/templates/article.js"
> The page object passed to createPage: {
> "path": "/blog/ukraine-national-guards-man-shoots-up-weapons-factory",
> "component": "/Users/t/WebDevelopment/xxxxx/src/templates/article.js",
> "context": {
> "id": "Post_2",
> "slug": "ukraine-national-guards-man-shoots-up-weapons-factory"
> } }
>
> See the documentation for the "createPage" action —
> https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/actions#createPage
>
> not finished createPages - 0.036s
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR!
> surprise_movie@1.0.0 develop: `gatsby develop` npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the surprise_movie@1.0.0 develop script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
> additional logging output above.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/t/.npm/_logs/2022-02-01T07_06_11_359Z-debug.log

file structure
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require(`path`)
const { paginate } = require('gatsby-awesome-pagination');

const makeRequest = (graphql, request) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(
      graphql(request).then(result => {
        if (result.errors) {
          reject(result.errors)
        }

        return result
      })
    )
  })

exports.createPages = ({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  // Get our articles
  const getPost = makeRequest(
    graphql,
    `
    {
      allStrapiPost{
        edges {
          node {
            id
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `
  ).then(result => {
    // Create pages for each article.
    result.data.allStrapiPost.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
      createPage({
        path: `/blog/${node.slug}`,
        component: path.resolve(`src/templates/article.js`),
        context: {
          id: node.id,
          slug: node.slug,
        },
      })
    })

    // Create pagination
    paginate({
      createPage, 
      items: result.data.allStrapiPost.edges, 
      itemsPerPage: 5, 
      pathPrefix: '/archives', 
      component: path.resolve('src/templates/blog-archive.js')
    })
  })

  // Query for articles nodes to use in creating pages.
  return getPost
}
```

Comment: Please don't invalidate answers by editing your old question out. Instead add to your question (like I have done for you), or ask a new question and include a link to this one for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite self-explanatory:

> ```
> ERROR #11325 Your site's "gatsby-node.js" created a page with a
> component that doesn't exist. The path to the missing component is
> "/Users/t/WebDevelopment/xxxxx/src/templates/article.js"
> ```

You don't have any template called `article.js` in `src/templates/article.js`. You only have one file called `blog-archive.js`.

If this is the supposed template file, just change `src/templates/article.js` for `src/templates/blog-archive.js` in your `gatsby-node.js`. Otherwise, if the file is missing, you'll need to create a new one.

Be careful when copying/pasting, try to understand what you are doing to anticipate these issues.

Comment: thanks,I have created an empty article.js.
But I got the same error.

Comment: Share your `gatsby-node.js` please

Comment: I added for question

Comment: The error is exactly the same?

Comment: yes,I added Image

Comment: The path is invalid. `templates` folder must be inside the `src` according to the path you are using.

Comment: oh,I missed.thanks! the error log changed.

Comment: I changed question text

Comment: It hasn't "changed", it has been solved. This is a new brand question. As I said, don't copy/paste without knowing what you are doing. If you copy just parts of the code, it will break because you don't have the full picture. Please look where is `ArticlePreview` is: is a component of `blog-arhive.js`. Because you copied just parts of the code, you don't have `ArticlePreview` so the code breaks. This is a completely different question related to React and importing/exporting components. If the issue has been solved please consider accepting the question to close the topic.